# Makefile, C++ build error: forward declaration

Tags: c++, makefile, structure

Hello i'm pass structure var to another file function using make utility  i am getting below error ppz help to fix it

1) var has incomplete type
2) header.h:error: foward declaration of struct st

Here is the code:

header.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void fn(struct st);
```

main.cpp

```
#include"header.h"

struct st
{
  int x;
  char s[10];
};
```

fn.cpp

```
#include"header.h"

void fn(struct st var)
{
  cout<<var.x<<var.s<<endl;
}
```

makefile

```
all: hello
hello: main.o fn.o
    g++ main.cpp fn.cpp

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

fn.o:fn.cpp
    g++ -c fn.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the struct st declaration to `header.h`, before `fn()`.